# Usefulness of the "contribution" tag

Tags: discussion, tags

A user has created a [contribution](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contribution) tag and [proposed the following definition](https://academia.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/12555) for the tag wiki excerpt:

> The authors, students and advisors contribution to an academic publication. Questions like how much contribution is needed to be a co-author of a paper best fits to this tag.

So far the tag has been applied to

- [How/when to become independent in research as a graduate student?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/24170/how-when-to-become-independent-in-research-as-a-graduate-student)
- [To what extent should a professor give students freedom to do independent research?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/24264/to-what-extent-should-a-professor-give-students-freedom-to-do-independent-resear)
- [Advisor's/University's rights in the PhD/MSc alumni's research projects and publications](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/24297/advisors-universitys-rights-in-the-phd-msc-alumnis-research-projects-and-publ)

(It's not clear to me, based on the suggested definition, how this tag is relevant to the first two.)

Is this tag useful and/or necessary? If so, can someone explain how it applies to the first two questions listed above?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think that this tag is unnecessary, given that the [authorship](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/authorship) tag is explicitly defined to include issues related to contribution to an academic publication.

It seems like this tag (unless defined much more narrowly) would overlap almost 100% with [authorship](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/authorship).

Comment: I would just call this a "synonym" for tagging purposes.

Comment: @aesmail we don't want synonyms, do we? How does that work?

Comment: I think it's exactly what we're looking for here. [Here's a how-to guide.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms)

Comment: @aeismail given that it's on only three questions, all three are bumped anyways, and I don't think it's appropriate on two of them, I would rather just delete the tag

Comment: Fair enough. (But the link is useful enough to keep handy for future reference!)