# How to decide for tag delete action

Tags: discussion, support

I have noticed that the moderator has deleted the tag I created `contribution`.

The process was this:

- She felt the tag is duplicate;
- She posted [a question on Meta](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1126/usefulness-of-the-contribution-tag) to ask about the usefulness of the tag;
- after less than one day (22 July), without any answers supporting to delete the tag The tag is deleted.

I want to know, how many answers in a delete proposal on meta is required to delete the tag?

I am feeling that the moderator is having wrong adaptation of the site's policies and is imposing her personal desires on new user; which she directly brings the user's problem to meta or chat and after one day, she does every thing she wants. Where is this policy written on help center, I have read the help center triple times and found no sign of such policy and process that described above.

This action is against the following instructions on help center because it was not patient, respectful, did not led by example and more important it was not fair.

When I read the [help center for this moderation action](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators),

> We generally expect that moderators:
>   - are patient and fair
>   - lead by example
>   - show respect for their fellow community members in their actions and words
>   are open to some light but firm moderation to keep the community on track and resolve (hopefully) uncommon disputes and exceptions

Comment: In that short time the answer by the same person calling for the deletion received 6 upvotes, which clearly indicates that there were people in agreement. And since it seemed quite clear that people agreed, it is usually a good idea to get rid of the tag before too many questions are tagged with it.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I have no complaint about why the tag is removed. I am arguing that such rapid actions is never indicated in the help center "as the only reference to site policies"; even, there is no answer supporting the idea of deleting the tag. It is clear that personal preferences are assumed to be the site policy which are completely against the written introductions in Help Center.

Comment: @Parsa: You have said below that you understand why the tag was deleted—because it was a duplicate. If that's the case, then how are "personal preferences" involved?

Comment: @aeismail Because I don't find any written instruction to the moderators to quickly do their preferences or whatever they want. It is written in help center that moderators are expected to be patient (as cited above). Do you assume such rapid action a patient one?! I don't think so.

Comment: "Patient" does not mean "wait for the community to make up its mind." "Patient" here means something closer to "help users work within the guidelines, even if they keep running afoul of the guidelines." That does not mean, though, that we just leave what we perceive to be in error to stand in the meantime.

Comment: If you do not "wait for the community to make up its mind.", bringing what *you want to do* to the meta to see what community thinks about is useless.

Comment: @Parsa historically anything on meta with more than 5 up votes represents a pretty clear consensus. There are not many things that have more than 10 up votes. Waiting longer doesn't seem to provide benefit and if a mod misjudges the community desire, the community can reverse the decision.

Comment: @StrongBad If we refer to help center of site, there is no regulation on deleting tags. There is no defined procedure like "bring it to meta and delete it immediately".

Comment: @Parsa: There's a clear strategy for expressing disapproval with an action—you post a question on meta about it, which you've done. You've also seen already that the votes are pretty strongly not in your favor. A moderator not handling things the way you feel they should be done is not a violation of your rights or privileges.

Comment: I am feeling that the moderation action towards me is not in the way described in help center: [Who are the site moderators, and what is their role here?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators)

Comment: In your view, what *should* someone do if they think there is something wrong with something you've done on this site?

Comment: @ff524 Moderators/Users have equal right on flagging.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by that. This isn't a question about flagging, it's a question about retagging. Any user with at least 2k rep can retag a question exactly as a moderator would (and any user can suggest a retag). There were no special moderator privileges in play here.

Comment: You asked about *something*. The problem here is that as a normal user you brought the problem to meta which was completely a right action. But in less than half a day, you used your moderation privilege to delete the tag (to reach the thing you personally wanted). This is completely against the normal behaviour which is expected from a moderator. You bring the problem to meta, and you solve your problem yourself by deleting the tag?!

Comment: Deleting a tag is not a moderation privilege. A tag is deleted automatically when there are no questions with the tag on them, which any 2k user can do by retagging the questions (which is exactly what I did). So actually, everything that happened here involved me acting as a normal user, not a moderator.

Comment: Being a moderator or a high reputation user makes no difference. Your impatience in deleting the tag is more important. Moreover, the un-used tags are automatically deleted in 6 months not in half a day!

Comment: And as a normal user, when still there is a discussion on the usefulness of tag, why did you re-tagged rapidly to delete the tag?! It is kind of bad use of a privilege.

Comment: The process that automatically removes unused tags runs [once per day](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251222/3524528) (possibly a different time of day on different SE sites). It takes less than 24 hours for an unused tag to be deleted (depending on what time the tag becomes unused, and what time the process runs on that site). Definitely not 6 months.

Comment: @ff524 1 hour, 1 day or 1 year; we are not discussing the time; why did you retag all the questions just to delete the tag you *prefer* not be in the site?! As a caring user you are trying to show, why don't you take a look at non-useful tags?! I am wondering, you say that you have no enough time and effort just to review the user's minor edits on tags, what was the reason that you spend time over bringing a problem to meta, discussing and answering it and in less than an hour, re-tagging and deleting it?! Seems you spent lots of time! Your wrong action and attitude towards me is so upsetting.

Comment: Your question seems to be: *why did I address problems with **this** tag instead of other, old tags?* The answer is, *because your edits bumped the questions with those tags to the top of the list, and so I noticed them.* I'm not under any obligation to go hunting for old things to fix on this site; I fix problems that come to my attention, and this came to my attention.

Comment: It is better to bring your wrong actions to your attention too. Moreover, it is also your wrong prefer that you don't like the old questions be bumped to the top of the list! It is a nice feature of the website that bring the edited questions to surface and encourages users to take a look at older questions too. Besides, if somebody wants the newest questions in the list, he can also use the feature to see the newest one. Remember, as a high reputation user or as a moderator, you have no duty to avoid any questions to be bumped to the top of the main list.

Comment: I'm not sure how bumping old questions is relevant here. I saw your new tag because it was at the top of the list; I realized it was a duplicate tag; I made sure the community felt the same way; then I fixed it. None of these actions were wrong. Your accusations against other users and moderators on this site of being "uncaring" "impatient" and "disrespectful', when we have spent a lot of time trying to help you understand the site governance and policies, is really not helping.

Comment: Yes, I accuse you and other moderators trying to show that your rapid action was a right thing, I accuse you for your every wrong action towards me (from the first day of being here), I accuse you for just giving the sense of "we are right and you are always wrong". I insist you are disrespectful, impatient and uncaring.

Comment: @Parsa Those "wrong actions" are purely so in your opinion. You are obviously very enthusiastic about participating in this site, which is great, but please try to slow down a bit and get to know how things are generally done around here before doing too many "moderation" things (such as editing things).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I appreciate this comment of yours indeed. But, doing edits is part of the privilege available to new users, so let's don't assume it "too many moderation things"; if new users were not allowed to do edit actions, they were banned by the website, not by these moderators preference that want to sit new users down and force them to stop and do whatever they want, not whatever is described in the site's help center. [continue to the next comment]

Comment: If it is too many edits, why the website has not put any limit on the number of edits each person can do on a day? They say we don't have enough time and effort to review your edits (!), if you don't have time why did you accept moderation responsibility? They *have* to review users edits, not just to reject their activities, not just to delete them. By this way, little by little, new users get used to the website's collaborative feature of edit. [continue to the next comment]

Comment: You think I'm wrong and I think their moderation behavior toward me is their pure opinion, not the website's policy. In the case of that tag, when she posted a question about the usefulness of the tag, I found it constructive. I was waiting for comments and answers to the question. But she rapidly answers her own question and suggestion to delete tag in less than half a day! I came back to work and saw she did what she wanted! It was amazing. Users should be respectful to each other by their actions, when she does not tolerate a new user's suggestion, how can I assume it a respectful behavior?

Answer (score 5):

The tag was deleted because it **was** a duplicate. There is nothing unique in the `contribution` flag that is not already covered by [authorship](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/authorship). I tried to find a counterexample under which such a tag would *complement* rather than simply "fork off," and couldn't come up with one. Moreover, I do agree that I don't see how the tag fit the questions you applied them to, which is also not a good sign.

One important point also to make: please don't treat "rollbacks" of your actions as personal attacks. The moderators are trying to make the community as useful as possible for everyone. One of the ways we do this is to keep things simple is to keep tag proliferation to a minimum. (Hence the decision to delete the tags.)

Comment: I have no complaint about "why it is deleted" but I don't find any reason to that rapid delete action; moderator should give time to discuss on the reasons. If every moderator does such rapid action, what will be the use of a "community"? There is no even a supporting answer to the suggestion in that short period of time!!

Comment: There was no additional answer—but why should there be? A sizable number of people "signed on" to the existing answer. Why should I or someone else post an additional answer that basically says "I agree with what's been said here." (Or do you mean an answer supporting _your_ viewpoint?)

Comment: But the point of moderators is to enable community moderation. You can't always wait for the community to develop a consensus. That's why Stack Exchange has moderators and "power users" to handle such issues.

Comment: I posted no answer, because I opened the tag; why should I support my action by extra useless supporting answers? When somebody opens a tag, it means that they are supporting the idea of a new tag.

Comment: You could have laid out in greater clarity _why_ you thought the tag was needed _in addition_ to the [tag:authorship] tag.

Comment: The problem here is not the tags or suggested edits, but rapid and impatient action of the moderator.

Comment: @Parsa based on your past behaviour, if we waited longer, you may have added the tag to tens of questions, making a lot of work to clean up. In general, as a new user, you may want to ask about things before acting. A meta question proposing the tag and highlighting some example questions to apply the tag to would have been very useful and avoided this issue.

Comment: @StrongBad Based on "you **may** have done something" you can not judge me. I am not an annoying or interrupting person. Moreover, as a moderator, you should be patient and show respect by your action and I don't think this comment of you shows respect in action to me.

Comment: @Parsa: You did "do something"—you applied the tag inappropriately to two of the three questions you did apply it to. That's enough.

Comment: @aeismail in which part of the help center is it written that two or three irrelevant application of tags should result tag delete? Also, there are many non-useful tags in the site that are linked to non-relevant questions, based on your comment, they also should be deleted but never deleted! Never edited! Even a new user edits them, he is banned and rejected!

Comment: It's written [here](http://academia.stackexchange.com/help/tagging): "As a general rule, you should avoid creating new tags if possible, and new users are not allowed to create new tags." The tag was clearly not needed, and ff524 was well within her rights to act.

Comment: And if you feel tags are being improperly used, flag them. If enough of your peers agree, things can be changed.

Comment: @aeismail [New users with 300 reputation or less](http://academia.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) are not allowed to create new tags automatically by website. Why are you referring this to answer me? Was I a user with less than 300 reputation on the day I created the tag?!

Comment: Since you have the reputation, you can create tags. However, the tag was a duplicate, and therefore unnecessary. ff524 was therefore free to delete the tag **without notification or warning**. You are free to make changes subject to what your reputation allows, but the mods and power users can "veto" changes they feel are not constructive. Those are the rules of how Stack Exchange sites work. If you don't like them, there's not much we can do about it—but you are no more entitled to exemptions from the rules than anyone else.

Comment: "[...] but you are no more entitled to exemptions from the rules than anyone else." Who wants exemptions from the rule?! I want the moderator and high reputation user to decide based on the written policy of the site, not her preferences; and to be patient, fair, respectful by her *actions* exactly as described in the help center of the site. Why don't you even think that rapid action rose such issue and you are just trying to say that *everything we do is right* and *everything you do is problematic*?

Comment: **Your actions were wrong here, not hers.** No amount of arguing on your part will change that fact. Her actions are consistent with the policies, **yours were not,** as I have shown you. If you are unwilling to see that, I cannot help you any further.

Comment: @aeismail "Her actions are consistent with the policies, yours were not [...]" You'd better to refer to written policies in the help center, not what you think is correct or your/her own preferences.

Answer (score 5):

In this community, it's not about waiting a specific length of time, but about waiting until we can see what the community wants. Once it is clear that there is community agreement on something - whether closing a question, deleting a tag, or something else - we act.

If there is a lot of disagreement on something - for example, a lot of back-and-forth between many users in the comments on whether to migrate a question - it's usually a good idea wait a bit before taking action. If there is not much disagreement - for example, if something has many votes in one direction and only a couple in the other direction - it's clear what the community wants, so we can take action more quickly. There is nothing to gain from waiting in that case.

In this case, the answer suggesting the tag is not useful or necessary had 7 upvotes and one downvote. There were no answers suggesting that the tag *is* useful or necessary. It seems like the majority of the community agrees that the tag is unnecessary, and there wasn't any ongoing debate on the issue, so I took action to delete it.

Note that tag deletion - like virtually all action on this site - can be undone. So if it turns out after a few days that the majority actually wants this new tag, we can reinstate it.

Comment: I can not see this policy in the "help center" but I can see there an instruction for the moderators to be patient and to respect the user's actions not only the way they talk to them, but also by their *actions*.

Comment: Moreover, why *you* should always be the one who is proposing deleting of *my* actions? If the other users of the community feel like my question needs any *rapid* action, they will propose it on meta or tag it. As an instance, how many users have proposed an edit on my questions in meta? I mean, how many of them brought such discussions about my posts on site to meta?! I can not understand why you always want to conflict me and show you are the *powerful moderator* who has the right to *stop* me?!

Comment: @Parsa When you comment on a new user's question that you think it needs improvement, or flag it for closure, are you trying to show that you are *powerful* and can *stop* them? Or just trying to improve the site? All I'm trying to do is help this site run according to what the majority of the community wants (as expressed through the community's flags, votes, and meta participation). I'm sorry if you can't see that.

Comment: Flagging or commenting is something different from rapid actions, making problem bold, bringing the problem to meta, etc. There are many many other tags on tag list which need more rapid action, why don't you take a look at them?!

Comment: And the situation becomes worse when a new user like me does review on the useless tags and *you*, again, stop me; constantly reject and ban me from doing further reviews for at least seven days (as a consequent of your impatient and not light and respectful moderation as described in help center of site). What happened next? I have no courage in reviewing tags anymore! This is the effect of *your* model of moderation and *your* preferred method of moderation under the shell of the policy of the site!

Comment: @Parsa: The SE review system is automated—we don't choose what comes up for review; that's determined by the users interacting with the system. When you change a tag, we get a notice; when a user with insufficient reputation edits a post, we get a notice; when someone casts a close vote, or recommends a question to be placed on hold, we are notified. The banning likewise is not imposed by the moderators, but is a consequence of having the changes rejected. (cont.)

Comment: @Parsa: As I mentioned in my reply above—we are not attacking you. You are clearly a motivated member of the community, and your participation is welcome. However, moderators need to act in the best interests of the site, not of individual users.

Comment: @aeismail I'm in favor of reviewing the user's activities as you described above; but rejecting the activities based on your preference of the policies is something non-constructive. As I mentioned here, the moderator doesn't care about the site's problematic tags, when something is proposed she bans it. I do not assume it to be a caring moderation act. Also I assume it to be using moderation tools to stop an enthusiast new user. If she is caring about the contents of the site, she'd better allow caring user to do his edit activity and put time and effort to review the edits, not just reject.

Comment: @Parsa: What is the more likely scenario: (a) Moderators have vendettas against an "enthusiast[ic] new user," or (b) moderators make decisions in the best interest of the site, and reject changes they feel are inappropriate, incorrect, or otherwise not helpful?

Comment: @aeismail Basically the second one but based on my experience, I am in doubt.

Comment: @parsa a number of your actions have resulted in regular users raising flags to alert moderators to possible issues. Most of the regular users chose to flag issues rather than bring them up in chat or meta. Many of these flags are for issues that are borderline and it is not clear if a moderator should take unilateral action. Based on when the flags are being raised, this results in ff524 handling most of these issues and therefore needing to raise the issues on meta to try understand the communities view.

Comment: @StrongBad I don't agree with you in the case of that tag which she brought to meta. It was her personal bad feeling about that tag not a moderation action.